# Problems with aligning in \parbox and \rule alignment

Tags: rules, alignment, parbox

I'm using the Twenty Seconds Resume/CV:

https://www.latextemplates.com/template/twenty-seconds-resumecv

https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/twenty-seconds-curriculum-vitae/kfgsngtymkfj

However I changed a quite some parts to my own taste. I'm having problems with aligning the text. I tried to explain my question as good as possible, hopefully it is understandable.

For example I first used this:

```
{\rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}} \newline
\begin{twenty} % Environment for a list with descriptions
    \twentyitemBLOCK{Short text1 Short text1 Short text1}{Long text2 Long text2 Long text2 Long}{Short text3 Short text3 Short text3}{Long text4 Long text4 Long text4 Long}
\end{twenty}
{\rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}}
```

where \twentyitemBLOCK is

```
\newcommand{\twentyitemBLOCK}[4]{%
    \textbf{#1}&\parbox{0.43\textwidth}{%
        \hfill%
        \footnotesize#2%
    }\\
    #3&\parbox{0.42\textwidth}{%
        \hfill%
        \footnotesize\textbf{#4}%
    }\\
}
```

And this will give the following layout:
[image]

However when text3 is long and text4 is short, it won't work properly. Even if I change the size of parbox:

```
{\rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}} \newline
\begin{twenty} % Environment for a list with descriptions
    \twentyitemBLOCKx{Short text1 Short text1}{Long text2 Long text2 Long text2 Long text2 Long text2}{Long text3 Long text3 Long text3 Long text3 Long text3}{Short text4 Short text4}
\end{twenty}
{\rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}}
```

with

```
\newcommand{\twentyitemBLOCKx}[4]{%
    \textbf{#1}&\parbox{0.6\textwidth}{%
        \hfill%
        \footnotesize#2%
    }\\
    #3&\parbox{0.25\textwidth}{%
        \hfill%
        \footnotesize\textbf{#4}%
    }\\
}
```

This will give the following layout:
[image]

I tried to fix this by defining the layout in the main .tex file like this:

```
{\rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}} \newline
\textbf{Short text1 Short text1} \hfill{\footnotesize{Long text2 Long text2 Long text2 Long text2 Long text2}} \\
Long text3 Long text3 Long text3 Long text3 Long text3  \hfill{\footnotesize{\textbf{Short text4 Short text4}}} \\
{\rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}}
```

But the second horizontal line will have an offset I can't get rid of:
[image]

Why is this? How can I fix this?
And why doesn't my \twentyitemBLOCKx approach work? They are just two lines independent of each other, but somehow the alignment isn't working like I want.

Comment: please don't post disconnected fragments, it makes it much harder to debug. Perhaps you are looking for `\parbox[t]` so that it aligns on the top line not vertically centred.

Comment: What do you mean with disconnected fragments? \parbox[t] didn't solve the problem unfortunately

Comment: I mean it always helps to post a single small test file, starting `\documentclass` ending `\end{document}` you have posted 5 separate fragments of code but we can not run them or debug them in any way so unless you get lucky and there is an obvious error that someone can spot by eye, it will be very hard for anyone to help you.

Comment: looking at the code `\hfill{\footnotesize{L...` looks wrong neither `\hfill` nor `\footnotesize` take an argument, what is the intention of the `{` here? (the first one limits the scope of the size) meaning that the `\\ ` will give an over-sized normal baeline line break not one based on the size of the text.